# Flutter getting 'ActionFactory' isn't a type Error

Tags: flutter, dart

after search many website to resolve this problem. i can't and when i try to run application i get this **error**:

```
Error: 'ActionFactory' isn't a type.
    Map<LocalKey, ActionFactory> actions,
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**flutter doctor output:**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.1 at F:\software\flutter
    • Framework revision 2ae34518b8 (7 days ago), 2020-08-05 19:53:19 -0700
    • Engine revision c8e3b94853
    • Dart version 2.9.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at F:\software\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = F:\software\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • WAS LX1A (mobile) • 2XJDU17C14006203 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Did you try what Flutter doctor suggest and run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @alexsafsafsd as I have remember me I upgraded some packages witch I used had used in flutter. But I'm not sure